# Mean response time vs Mean turnaround time

Tags: performance

I'm confused about the meaning and usage of response time and turnaround time. As far as I know, response time is the time between the arrival of a task until the first response (first step to execute the task) and the turnaround time is the time between arrival of a task to the completion of the task execution, but I found this formula for average response time in several research paper [[1]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7966813/) and [[2]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4359403/):

ART = 1/N ∑ (Finish_Time - Arrival_Time)

Arrival_Time is when a task arrives and Finish_time is when the task leaves the system.

Does this formula represent Average response time or average turnaround time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`finish time - arrival time` represents `average turnaround time` ... because it does not differ in between arrival time, validating the input, processing the input, preparing the response, sending the response and response fully delivered. where the `average response time` is the time it takes to respond, not considering the arrival time, nor processing of the input request.

`I/O` always means turnaround - which can be broken down to `I` (request) vs. `O` (response).

this chart visualizes it; they just call it `average think time`, what I call "preparing the response":

[image: Average Response Time]

[image source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4741/abfch/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is  **Average turnaround time**. The answer is in the question

> As far as I know, response time is the time between the arrival of a task until the first response

The equation is not this because `time to first response` is not one of the variables.

> turnaround time is the time between arrival of a task to the completion of the task

The equation is this because `Finish_Time` is when the `when the task leaves the system`.

I would strongly suggest that `completing a task` and the `task leaving the system` are referring in different terms to the same event in this context.

Comment: I mean completing the task, so the "Average turnaround time" is correct?